# How do i calculate this definite integral of $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be defines as : $$f(x)=\prod^{2009}_{r=1}(x-r)$$
then the value of the definite integral  $$\int^{2009}_1f(x) .dx \text{  is equal to? }$$

In this question, $f(x)$ is clearly polynomial with degree  $2010$ , so am I supposed to solve the whole integral? Please someone help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this property might be of interest to you:
$$\int^a_bf(x)=\int^a_bf(a+b-x)$$

and thus $$I=\int^{2009}_1(2009-x)(2008-x)...(x-1) \tag{1}$$
becomes equivalent to
$$I=-\int^{2009}_1(2009-x)(2008-x)...(x-1) \tag{2}$$

Add $(1) ,(2)$ to get $I=0$